# Is the infinite union of given sets closed or open?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a homework question, and i need to determine whether the following union $\cup _{n=1} ^ \infty I_n$ is either an open or a closed set, where $I_n = [0,a_n]$ and $a_n=\cos \frac{\pi}{2n}+i \sin \frac{\pi}{2n}$.

Here, $[0,a_n]$ represents a line segment in the complex plane joining $0$ and $a_n$. 
I know that the infinite union of closed sets are not necessarily closed.

Here i am unable to determine what happens when $n$ becomes infinite.

I would be happy for reasons to be provided. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $[0,z]$ when $z$ is a complex number.

Comment: $[0,a_n]$ represents the line segment in complex plane joining $0$ and $a_n$.

Comment: @User101: when n-->oo , a_n-->(1,0).

Comment: The angle goes to zero. You'll have infinite number of segments from the vertical one going to the horizontal one.

Comment: You use the following terminology : "the following union is either an open or a closed set". Do you think that any set has to be either closed or open ?

Actually, most sets are neither open nor closed (and some are both !)

Comment: @User101 : you need to define what $[0,a_n]$ means in the question, not just in a comment.  Someone else remarked correctly that many sets are neither open nor closed.  I suggest you sketch the set.

Comment: @Sigur: I didn't mean that the segment _is_ along the Real line, only that the endpoint approaches (1,0).

Comment: @user99680, neither me. $\theta\neq 0$.

Comment: @Sigur: yes; $\theta$  approaches the limiting value $0$ , but never actually takes it. This is why the set is not closed--it does not contain the limit segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$.

Comment: @just: Maybe the OP only wants to know whether the set is open or whether its closed.

Comment: @user99680 Yes of course, I just wanted to make sure, just in case, since i've seen fellow students make this mistake more than once. Maybe because our topology course was very abstract and didn't come with a lot of examples.

Comment: @just: no problem, I'm open ( or at least not closed) to comments like yours to0 ;).

Answer (score 4):

The set is not open in $\mathbb R^2$ , since every open neighborhood of the set intersects the complement. And it is not closed, since it does not contain the limiting point/segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$

Comment: No problem, glad to help.